# How to ask LightOpenId to get the users email in checkid_immediate mode?

Tags: php, openid, lightopenid

### Premises:

- I am using php LightOpenId to authenticate a users through his google account.
- I am using the standard sample provided (example.php) from the website.  Nothing fancy.
- Adding one line or two to change the behavior.
- All my clients are Googlers.

### Requirement1

I do not want my client to log twice (SSO behavior), so I add the 
  `$openid->mode=checkid_immediate` before calling 
  `header...$openid->authUrl()`.

### I experience 2 problems:

1. I cannot get the email, lang ... attributes.

   In fact, using checkid_immediate mode and following with the `authUrl()` 
   I get my user connected correctly as expected.

   **BUT** Modifying the code and adding the `$openid->required` to gather the attributes
   prior the `authUrl()` request forces my call to be converted into a `checkid_setup` mode
   call.

   **How can I, in one call, keep the checkid_immediate mode and get my attributes ?**
2. `subdomain.mydomain2.com` code do not behave like `www.mydomain1.com`
   The `www.mydomain1.com` works fine with the `checkid_immediate`.
   The `subdomain.mydomain2.com` with the same code is converted into a `checkid_setup` call.

   **How can I keep the `checkid_immediate` mode with a subdomain different than www ?**

   **Problem #2 solved by itself!!! after clearing cache AND restarting Google Chrome**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.5 the authUrl method has an optional bool parameter to check immediately. Try:

```
if (!$openid->mode && !empty($storedIdentity)) {
  $openid->identity = $storedIdentity;
  $openid->required = array('contact/email', 'pref/language');
  header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl(true));
}
```

*Edited code example to include question's requested attributes.
This presumes $storedIdentity is the identity url returned from checkid_setup previously.

Comment: I tried it, but without success.  I still cannot get the email from the attributes in the "checkid_immediate"

Comment: I expanded the example above.  The example should return the attributes the same way as normal.  They can then be accessed by $openid->getAttributes() when $openid->mode == 'id_res'.

If you still can't get this working there may be a problem somewhere else in your code, or you may be using an older version of LightOpenID.

Also, the LightOpenID::authUrl method does not use the LightOpenID::mode property when generating the URL. Setting this before calling authUrl will have no effect.  Hope this helps

Comment: $storedIdentity should be the identity url saved in a cookie after the first checkid_setup. If you use the regular Google url or the user has unlinked their account to your realm then they will be returned with mode set to 'id_res' but without attributes and validate() will return false.